# Is there a command-line or Ruby text indexing tool with stopword and connected-word support?

Tags: command-line, markdown, nlp, ruby, document-indexing

I have a book written in Markdown/Markua, separated into chapters. Currently, it consists of about 26 individual *.md files. I'm planning to write an index for the book, but I'm unable to find a command-line utility or Ruby gem that will do the following:

1. Provide a word-frequency list from the .md input files that I can sort alphabetically or by count. (NB: This is the relatively easy part, as Ruby can use `str.split.tally` to generate a hash. I can roll my own for this part, if necessary.)
2. Provide a *reliable* list of editable stopwords to remove from the frequency list. I've found several on the web, including [this one from MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), but they all vary enough to seem non-canonical.
3. Allow treating certain phrases ("connected words") that are relevant to the domain as individual items. For example, "Scrum Master" ought to be treated as a single word for indexing, rather than two.
4. Support for inflections and contractions, e.g. `octopus => octopi` and `Scrum's, Scrums => Scrum`.
5. (Optional) Bonus points if the indexing can point to source files or line numbers as well. This is less critical because I can use ack, grep, ag, or other similar tools to locate the indexed items, but it's a "nice to have."

A GUI like IndexMakerS doesn't seem helpful, as it only works on PDF files, and doesn't seem to allow command-line editing of the stopwords and phrases. As a programmer (but not an NLP expert) I've also tried to integrate stopwords, connected words, and inflections into a coherent hash when rolling my own code, but it's a little more complex than I'd anticipated.

Most importantly, **the end goal isn't to just generate the frequency list, but to use the top X% of the filtered list to programmatically insert index and cross-link markup into my Markdown/Markua documents**. While it would be nice if there was a tool that did that cross-linking for me, that's probably a step too far as Markua is a fairly specialized use case. I'll cross that bridge myself if I can find something to do the heavy lifting of properly indexing the words and phrases I need.

As long as I have the editable lists and can extract the words/phrases I'm looking for, I can programmatically insert the markup I need. I've tried searching for phrases like `command line index generator` on the web, but haven't turned up any meaningful results.

Is there a Linux, Mac, or BSD tool that will do what I'm trying to accomplish?